# Can i use a modified version if ubuntu's logo with or without canonical's Permission

Tags: canonical, logo, legal

Could I Use A modified Version of **ubuntu** logo for An OS based on Debian With Or Without Canonicals Permission

Comment: You certainly could **with** their permission.

Comment: You are asking for free legal advice. This is the wrong place for free legal advice. Your lawyer specializing in trademarks and copyrights should start their research at https://ubuntu.com/legal/trademarks

Comment: We are not allowed to provide legal info. Nor does any "advice" you do get hold any value even if from someone who claims to be an official employee. You need to contact Canonical and get formal written consent.